# Break in Foreach after 3 rows

Tags: c#, pdf, gridview, foreach

I am trying to after each 3 loops in my `foreach` do a page break but can't seem to get it to trigger. Any help is welcome here is my code it prints fine but I'd like 3 GridView rows per page.

```
 int i = 0;
        // for each row in Gridview do this part of the PDF print
        foreach (GridViewRow row in poGridview.Rows)
        {
            if ((i++) % 3 == 0)
            {
                pdfDoc.NewPage();
            }

            // Declare all values
            String itemNum = row.Cells[0].Text;
            String house = row.Cells[2].Text;
            String staic = row.Cells[4].Text;
            String description = row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&amp;", "");
            String qtOrd = row.Cells[5].Text;
            String serial = row.Cells[12].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
            String dkQty = row.Cells[8].Text;
            String stQty = row.Cells[9].Text;
            String deptNum = row.Cells[11].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); ;
            String whBarCode = row.Cells[13].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
            String turnA = row.Cells[19].Text;
            String turnN = row.Cells[20].Text;
            String turnC = row.Cells[21].Text;
            String conversion = row.Cells[7].Text;
            String unit = row.Cells[6].Text;
            decimal ucorq = decimal.Parse(qtOrd) - decimal.Parse(stQty);

            // Warehouse barcode
            Barcode39 whlsc = new Barcode39();
            whlsc.Code = whBarCode.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");

            // Turn around barcode
            Barcode39 turnAr = new Barcode39();
            turnAr.Code = (poNum + "$I" + itemNum + "$M");

            // Set up lines for paragraph 
            Paragraph itemLine1 = new Paragraph(@"" + itemNum + "              " + house + "              " + description, body);
            Paragraph itemLine2 = new Paragraph(@"          Status -> " + staic + "                                          Ordered:      " + qtOrd + " " + unit, body);
            Paragraph itemLine3 = new Paragraph(@"STOCKING: " + stQty + " EA          CONVERSION FACTOR: " + conversion + "     ", body);
            Paragraph itemLine4 = new Paragraph(@"Dock: " + dkQty + "                    Stock: " + stQty + "                         Open:     " + ucorq.ToString(), body);
            Paragraph itemLine5 = new Paragraph(@"Serial #: " + serial, body);
            Paragraph itemLine6 = new Paragraph(@"VND CATALOG: " + serial + "   ", body);
            Paragraph itemLine7 = new Paragraph(@"JOB NUMBER: " + "                                        DEFAULT STOCK LOC: ", body);
            Paragraph itemLine8 = new Paragraph(@"                                                                                                                           ", body);


            // Select command for the comments for each item
            OleDbCommand comtSearch = new OleDbCommand("SELECT CAST(POCOMT.CMNT1 as char(40) ccsid 37) as cmt1, CAST(POCOMT.CMNT2 as char(40) ccsid 37) as cmt2 FROM POCOMT LEFT OUTER JOIN POITEM ON POITEM.ITNBR = POCOMT.ITNBR"
                + $" AND POITEM.ORDNO = POCOMT.ORDNO AND POITEM.HOUSE = POCOMT.HOUSE AND POITEM.LINSQ = POCOMT.LINSQ WHERE POCOMT.ITNBR = '{itemNum}' AND POCOMT.ORDNO = '{poNum}'", cn);

            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(comtSearch);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            commentGridview.DataSource = dt;
            commentGridview.DataBind();


            // Add Lines to page
            p.Add(itemLine1);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

            p.Add(new Chunk(turnAr.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(itemLine2);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(itemLine3);
            //p.Add(new Chunk(turnAr.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(itemLine4);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            //p.Add(itemLine5);         

            // loop through the comment fields on each item and print
            foreach (GridViewRow cmtRow in commentGridview.Rows)
            {
                String cmnt1 = cmtRow.Cells[0].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); ;
                String cmnt2 = cmtRow.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); ;
                Paragraph cmt1 = new Paragraph(@"" + cmnt1, body);
                Paragraph cmt2 = new Paragraph(@"" + cmnt2 + " ", body);
                p.Add(cmt1);
                p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
                p.Add(cmt2);
            }

            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(itemLine6);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(itemLine7);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(itemLine8);
            p.Add(new Chunk(whlsc.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(hr);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

        }


        p.Add(end);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

    pdfDoc.Add(p);
    pdfDoc.NewPage();
    }
    // Close Document
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Well in the code example you never increase the value of `i` so it's never 3.

Comment: in else part increment the i

Comment: Considering you aren't incrementing `i`, it isn't surprising that `i` remains `0`.

Comment: Might be better to use a For loop here.  I know that's not the thrust of your issue, but For loops can be a hair faster and your i would be built-in nicely.

Answer (score 2):

```
   int i = 0; //initiate variable outside foreach loop
   foreach (GridViewRow row in poGridview.Rows)
   {
      if (i == 3)
      {
         pdfDoc.NewPage();
         i=0; //when i=3, resets to 0 and calls newPage method
      }
      i++; //+1 to i
   }
```

Comment: Tried this also, still no luck. Even cleared cache on web browser.  Still runs all rows one after another with no break after 3.

Comment: @tstrathman feel free to choose one of the answers if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting i to zero at the beginning of every iteration of the loop.  So, it never gets to 3.  You probably want something like this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach( GridViewRow row in poGridview.Rows )
{
    if( i % 3 == 0 && i > 0 )
    {
        pdfDoc.Add(p);
        pdfDoc.NewPage();
        p = <Create a new p>
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense... tried that code and it still isn't working and I know that the pdfDoc.NewPage works because I use it after the for each to break between PO numbers.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then there's more going on than we can see from your posted question.  You definitely tried it with the "i = 0" part before the foreach statement?

Comment: Correct.. i posted full code above for that foreach now.

Comment: @Gianlucca, your answer is better than mine: slightly better performance, and yours will work when there are more than 2,147,483,647 rows, (mine won't).  :-)

Comment: @Jaquar only has 130 or so rows! posted my full code above not sure if something is causing it to not work that I have coded in the foreach?

Comment: @tstrathman, so it's still not giving you page breaks?  Even though you accepted my answer?

Comment: it is not sorry about that!

Comment: @tstrathman, no worries.  I'm not sure what else could be wrong.  Sorry.

Comment: it must be the pdfDoc.NewPage() causing the issue.. i can do a pdfDoc.Add(hr) and it puts a horizontal row after the 3rd one.  So your code works great just its not triggering the new page.

Comment: I don't know much about GridView, but I beginning to think that, by default, you can't break it up into different pages.  However, googling around, I found a couple places that discuss how to do it: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Print-ASPNet-GridView-with-page-breaks-and-repeat-header-on-each-page.aspx and https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1103462/Print-ASP-NET-gridview-with-page-breaks-and-repeat

Comment: See thats the thing... outside that foreach loop I do a pdfDoc.AddPage and it works perfectly... basically separate after each PO.  So it's weird that this one doesn't work when it works fine in a different foreach loop.

Comment: I just updated my answer.  It looks like you're acclumulating your rows in p, but not adding it to the doc until later.  So, you're really calling pdfDoc.NewPage() multiple times in a row before adding the content.  And that doesn't really work.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430019/document-newpage-not-adding-new-page   If that works, I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: When I do that it creates a bunch of blank pages for some reason as compared to just starting a new page with the next loop of the foreach..

Comment: i've tried adding blank lines before and after and instead of a 26 page doc it turns into 59 pages... but if i just put pdfDoc.Add(hr) it adds an HR after every third row like it should but cant get the .NewPage() to trigger at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
foreach(GridViewRow row in poGridview.Rows)
{
    if ((i++) % 3 == 0)
    {
        pdfDoc.NewPage();
    }
}
```