# Document.NewPage() not working in foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, itext

I have a `foreach` loop that after 3 rows of a gridview I want a new page started then add a few lines.  The `foreach` is working fine because it adds my few lines just fine but can't get the `NewPage()` to work? If i do the `writer.PageEmpty = false` it creates a bunch of blank pages.  What am I missing?

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in poGridview.Rows)
{
    if (i == 3)
    {
        writer.PageEmpty = false;
        pdfDoc.NewPage();
        p.Add(line1);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(line2);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(hr);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

        i = 0;
    }
    i++; 
}
```

Comment: what is `p` and is it the same as `pdfDoc`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Document.NewPage() not adding new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430019/document-newpage-not-adding-new-page)

Comment: p is a paragraph after this gridview I add all the p's to the pdfDoc using pdfDoc.Add(p);

Comment: @crashmstr that is where I got the writer.PageEmpty idea from... still having no luck getting it to trigger the NewPage

Comment: If that is what you started from, you ended up with very different looking code (and why it may not be working).

Comment: @crashmstr not sure what you mean... i was reading that article and thought I'd try adding the pageEmpty to my code I already had to see if that made it work.

Comment: The accepted answer adds `new Paragraph(...)` objects to the document, your code is showing no such thing. That is different. That might be the reason yours is not working.

Comment: My code has several new paragraphs ....

Comment: ...that are not added directly to the document that had `NewPage()` called on it. That. Is. Different. You are adding to `p` and not to `pdfDoc`.

Comment: Ahh makes sense.. when I add that it throws off my whole document for some reason.. I have several for eachs this happens to be the one that I want after 3 products create new page... isn't wanting to do that.  If I do pdfDoc.Add(new paragraph("test")) it adds 30 pages with just test at the top.  I'll keep messing with it must have something to do with the way my for each is set up

Answer (score 0):

After adding a new page you need to start with a new paragraph, not reuse the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Had to create a new phrase and assign those values to that to make it work..

```
Phrase p2 = new Phrase();
            if (i == 3)
            {
                pdfDoc.NewPage();
                p2.Add(line1);
                p2.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
                p2.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
                p2.Add(line2);
                p2.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
                p2.Add(hr);
                p2.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
                i = 0;
            }
            i++;
```